# Does the ground wire need to be continuous through the termination block?

Tags: electrical, grounding-and-bonding

I need to re-route where the ground wire goes through the exterior wall. From the panel, it is run continuous through a termination block (picture below), through the exterior wall, then out to the ground rod. Can I cut the wire here to re-route, then connect it back to the termination block? Or does it need to remain continuous? I can of course disconnect it from the panel but it would be much faster/easier to just cut it here.

[image: Ground termination block]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ground has to be continuous, code allows splicing with non removable splices that are rated for grounding.

There are many splices out there but not all are listed for grounding make sure the splice you get is listed for grounding.

The second thing is the proper compression tool. I have had inspectors that wanted “stamped” marks from the compression tool proving the correct tool was used, I haven’t had that issue for many years but be aware it could be and make sure you have enough wire to redo the splice if the inspector calls you on it (both the splice or the compression tool used).

You can not use terminal blocks from the electrode(s) the grounding wire can only be spliced with non removable means as compression or cad welding.

Comment: Can you provide the code reference?

Comment: 2020 NEC 250.64.C. Continuous….  250.64.C.1  splicing of the wire type grounding conductor shall be permitted by irreversible compression type connectors listed as grounding & bonding. Yes if an inspector sees a splice they will look for it to be listed! This in one place they get very picky!